# Are there a function for erc1155 like this function isValidSignatureNow?

Tags: erc-1155, mint

i used to use for erc720 this function isValidSignatureNow, but now i am working with erc1155 i need a function like that.

i am trying to mint but before i need to know if that wallet can mint for that i created a function `isAvailable` but right now i am getting

> TypeError: Member "isValidSignatureNow" not found or not visible after
> argument-dependent lookup in address.
> --> Migrations.sol:112:16: |

how can i solve that error?

if i fixed that error, my code is looking good to mint?

```
    function isAvailable(
        bytes memory signature, address _firmante
    ) internal view returns (bool whiteListed) {
        bytes32 result = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(msg.sender)
        );
        //doing hash by result
        hash= ... // dont care yet
        return isValidSignatureNow(_firmante, hash, signature);
    }
```

i want to use this function 'isValidSignatureNow' from : https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/utils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your `contract` with SignatureChecker.sol from openzeppelin like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/SignatureChecker.sol";

contract SignatureCheckerMock {
    using SignatureChecker for address;

    function isValidSignatureNow(address signer, bytes32 hash, bytes memory signature) public view returns (bool) {
        return signer.isValidSignatureNow(hash, signature);
    }
}
```

Comment: please with erc1155 not erc720

Comment: @signup this has nothing to do with erc721  or erc1155. This is a library that can be used in any contract and your job is to use it at the correct place in your logic :)

Comment: @MajdTL but i am getting this error Member "isValidSignatureNow" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.

Comment: TypeError: Member "isValidSignatureNow" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.
--> Migrations1.sol:134:16:
|
134 | return _signer.isValidSignatureNow(hash, signature);
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^